# dynamic, scheduled push notifications using Celery (Django)

Tags: django, push-notification, celery, django-celery, django-celery-beat

I have a model called `Schedule` which consists of a list of `Task`. Below is the json representation

```
{
  id: 1,
  tasks: [
    {
      id: 1,
      date: "2020-09-08",
      message: "xyz",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      date: "2020-09-10",
      message: "xyz",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      date: "2020-09-17",
      message: "xyz",
    },
  ],
};
```

So my question is how do I setup celery to intiate a task which notifies the user(Firebase push notifications) on all the respective `dates` for the given schedule (The schedules are generated dynamically! throught a GraphQL api)

Any alternative technology is also welcomed (it should work with Django though!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily using periodic tasks in celery

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html